# how to read ,increment by one and write back value to a network file location

Tags: python

I am trying to read a value from a file "build_ver.txt" on a network location,increment the value by one and write back the incremented new value to "build_ver.txt" and running into following error,can anyone provide suggetions on how to achieve this?

```
with open('\\network\files\build_ver.txt','w+') as f:
    value = f
    value = value+1

value_inc = open('\\network\files\build_ver.txt','w+')
value_inc.write(value)
```

ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_ver.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open('\\network\files\build_ver.txt','w+') as f:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w+') or filename: '\\network\x0ciles\x08uild_ver.txt'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backslashes escape special Characters, in your case '\f': form-feed and '\b': bell. You have to escape the backslash with another backslash or use the r''-Syntax. Next problem: you don't read the file, you only rename the object. If you would read the object, you would have a string and not a number, and if you would convert the string to a number you couldn't write it because it's not a string. All in all you get this:

```
with open(r'\\network\files\build_ver.txt','r+') as f:
    value = int(f.read())
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(str(value + 1))
```

Comment: You want to use 'r+' as the file mode, because otherwise the version number will be erased before you read it.

Answer (score 2):

In python backslashes are used as escape sequences. Here is what happens if I type in your string:

```
>>> '\\network\files\build_ver.txt'
'\\network\x0ciles\x08uild_ver.txt'
>>> print '\\network\files\build_ver.txt'
\network
        ileuild_ver.txt
>>>
```

Instead, change your code to:

```
value_inc = open('\\network\\files\\build_ver.txt','w+')
value_inc.write(value)
```

As shown:

```
>>> print '\\network\\files\\build_ver.txt'
\network\files\build_ver.txt
>>>
```

Comment: am getting the following error now..  File "build_ver.py", line 3, in <module>
    value = value+1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'file' and 'int'

Comment: Please post your full code in your question by editing it; looks like you haven't posted this code yet.

Comment: You cannot add 1 to an open file. Maybe you want to loop over the contents of the file first...